# How to investigate issues with access to a specific IP

Tags: ip, routing, vpn, openvpn

I am connecting with VPN and I need the traffic to the remote address 192.168.1.109 to go through that VPN. Sometimes it works, sometimes it does not. I suspect that it is caused by the collision in addressing between the network behind the VPN and my LAN.
I do not have access to my LAN gateway (I'm renting my home and I do not have access to the router), so I can't change my LAN address space.
My suspicion is caused by the fact that everything works perfectly fine as soon as I switch my internet access point to my phone's hot spot.

I checked my routing table with `ip r`, and I saw that in theory it should just work:

```
default via 172.20.10.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 172.20.10.5 metric 100 
default via 10.8.152.1 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp src 10.8.155.218 metric 600 
5.32.152.131 via 10.251.182.1 dev tun0 
6.6.6.6 via 10.251.182.1 dev tun0 
10.0.0.24 via 10.251.182.1 dev tun0 
10.0.0.64 via 10.251.182.1 dev tun0 
10.0.0.74 via 10.251.182.1 dev tun0 
10.0.0.75 via 10.251.182.1 dev tun0 
10.0.0.85 via 10.251.182.1 dev tun0 
10.1.0.0/24 via 10.251.182.1 dev tun0 
10.1.15.0/24 via 10.251.182.1 dev tun0 
10.1.20.0/23 via 10.251.182.1 dev tun0 
10.2.0.0/24 via 10.251.182.1 dev tun0 
10.8.152.0/21 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.155.218 metric 600 
10.32.0.0/16 via 10.251.182.1 dev tun0 
10.64.0.0/16 via 10.251.182.1 dev tun0 
10.90.1.0/24 via 10.251.182.1 dev tun0 
10.96.0.0/11 via 10.251.182.1 dev tun0 
# ... a lot of lines ...
188.117.137.130 via 10.251.182.1 dev tun0 
188.165.234.213 via 10.251.182.1 dev tun0 
192.168.1.0/24 via 10.251.182.1 dev tun0
# ... a lot of lines ...
```

`tun0` is my OpenVPN interface and it seems that the routing table is already configured to use it. Why my traffic sometimes gets to the right destination, and sometimes it does not?
When it does not work, `curl` returns this:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.1.109 port 80 after 50 ms: Connection refused
```

Comment: Can you try a `ip r g 192.168.1.109` the next time it fails, then you can see specifically how the kernel wants to route traffic to that IP.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like it uses the right interface: `192.168.1.109 dev tun0 src 10.251.182.54 uid 1000 
    cache`. However, the communication via curl (or web browser) does not work.

Comment: Then it's probably not the addressing collision you suspect. Do you have access to 192.168.1.109, so you can see if it logs why it doesn't want to talk to you? Otherwise I would probably continue with `tcpdump` to see if there is any difference to the generated traffic between when it work and when it doesn't.